# vulnerability issue changing spring boot version 2.7.1 to 3.0.5

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

Due spring vulnerability issue CVE-2023-20860, we have 2 options available.
Options 1: Change to 2.7.11
We changed spring boot version from 2.7.1 to 2.7.11 while application started successfully and service invoked successfully. Below entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true","-jar","/app/app.jar"]

But again, during image vulnerability scan we are seeing log4j-core 2.12.1 vulnerability. We checked the dependency but not able to find the log4j-core anywhere in the tree. Below dependency tree snapshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYkXA.png)

Options 2: Change to 3.0.5
We changed the version from 2.7.1 to 3.0.5 and apache camel version 4.0.0-M2, while application started successfully, but we are getting HTTP 404

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5iYx.png)

We changed the version from 2.7.1 to 3.0.5 and Apache camel version 4.0.0-M2, while application started successfully, but we are getting HTTP 404

Comment: Just upgrade to 2.7.11 and ignore the log4j one. The dependency check/vulnerability checks are generally pretty dumb, I suspect you see this because of the slf4j log4j dependencies/includes. Which replace the log4j classes. If you are really worried you can always set the `log4j2.version` property to a new log4j2 version.

Comment: we added <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version> property also and still its giving vulnerability.

Comment: Because, as stated, vulnerability checks are dumb. They check the actual included dependencies including the transitive ones. It doesn't check the end resulting pom but all individual dependencies.